# React js routing not working on server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

can anyone tell what's wrong with my code?

All routes works on localhost (HashRouter) but on server the last route does not work. When I access https:www.example.com/invoice_data/a/b -> only "spinner" is visible which looks like the const isFetched is false, but it is not, because other routes works correctly.

```
render(){
const {language, langRequest} = this.props;
  const isFetched = langRequest.isFetched;
  let intlData = {};
  if (isFetched) {
     intlData = {
        locale: language,
        messages: langRequest.localeData[language].data
     };
     return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (
         <IntlProvider key="intl" {...intlData}>
             <BrowserRouter>
                 <Switch>
                     <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <p>Home</p>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="terms_list"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms/licence' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="licence"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms/personal' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="personal"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/password/:hash' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="password" {...props}/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/invoice_data/:hash/:idata' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="invoice" {...props}/>}/>
                     <Route component={NotFound}/>
                 </Switch>
             </BrowserRouter>
         </IntlProvider>
     ) : (
         <IntlProvider key="intl" {...intlData}>
             <HashRouter>
                 <Switch>
                     <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <p>Home</p>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="terms_list" footer="sticky"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms/licence' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="licence"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/terms/personal' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="personal"/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/password/:hash' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="password" {...props}/>}/>
                     <Route exact path='/invoice_data/:hash/:idata' render={(props) => <ExtraPage content="invoice" {...props}/>}/>
                     <Route component={NotFound}/>
                 </Switch>
             </HashRouter>
         </IntlProvider>
     )
  }else{
     return(
         <div className="loader-container centerizeH">
             <div className="loader">
                 <div className="spinner">
                     <div className="dot1"></div>
                     <div className="dot2"></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     )
  }
 }
```

.htaccess config:

```
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: this might be an issue on your server handling, can you provide some info on your server setup?

Comment: I added the htaccess file config. Do you mean some specific info?